# how to add a virtual directory on a remote machine IIS 6

Tags: iis-6, directory, virtualization, scripting

We have a build script to add a Virtual Directory to an existing website running on the same server.

it works fine,

is it possible to add a virtual directory to a remote machine? which the user has access and authorisation for.

the script we are using is a simple .bat file the commandline for  is is as below

```
SET appName=myApp
set pathName= myApp


rem -- the below statement will creates the web application  under IIS for you
c:\Windows\System32\inetsrv\appcmd add app /site.name:"Default Web Site" /path:/%appName% /physicalPath:d:\websites\ultimate\%pathName%
```

Comment: appcmd on IIS6? Not II7 on Server 2003?

Answer (score 1):

Have a look at the "iisvdir.vbs" script (in %SystemRoot%\System32) that installs w/ IIS 6. I believe that this script will do what you want.